# How to prevent TinyMCE editor within Wordpress from changing the html markup?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I'm trying to write some html in the "Html" tab of TinyMCE while editing my page and the editor keeps modifying my markup when I save the page. For example it removes my `<br>` tags and replaces my `<i>` tags with `<em>`.

Is there any place I can turn this "AUto Correct" feature completely off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to know that there are two levels of correction.

1. Tinymce
2. the browser

In your case it looks as of your tinymce configuration is not set propperly.
Please check your tinymce configuration for the settings [valid_elements](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements) and [valid_children](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_children).

Comment: Good call on the browser. I switched to Chrome (from FireFox) and looks like my HTML markup remains as it is. The TinyMCE settigns should be ok however as this website is a clean install of Wordpress with no plugins.

Comment: The 3rd level of correction is in the WordPress codebase, it contains two versions of correction functions (one server-side and one client-side) that don't do the same type or even sequence of manipulations.  As a result HTML can be altered in different ways.

Answer (score 2):

This Plugin will fix your Problem: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/preserved-html-editor-markup/

It disables "wpautop" that is responsible for the "Auto Correction".

Comment: Thanks for posting my plugin.  Just wanted to say that I've updated the code to provide even more consistency between browsers and improved support for script blocks.  This is fixed on both the server side and client side so you can still switch between the two editors.

Answer (score 0):

WordPress will edit your html by converting line breaks to paragraphs etc. If you want to add html through the text editor and not have it get broken later use a plugin like the RAW HTML plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/raw-html/

Comment: Thanks for the plugin. I try to stay away from adding too many plugins, but if nothing works out, I'll give this a try.